# Some synchronization questions

Tags: android, mysql, json, sqlite

I am making an app and I have some problems I'd like to ask about whether my solutions are good.

So basically I use a `Service` which I start with `Intent` from my `MainActivity`. That `Service` has an endless loop in it, which has a `Thread`. `Sleep(60000)` so it tries to update only every 60 secs. The `Service` makes an HTTP request to my JSON wrapper PHP script, it then returns data from my remote MySQL database, then the `Service` parses the data, after that it communicates with a `ContentProvider` and uses its `bulkInsert()`  with replace instead of insert so older rows get replaced if needed to store the new data in a local `SQLiteDatabase`. I've figured besides the JSON data I also have to get a list of valid id's so it knows to delete rows that no longer exist in the main db, also I send the time of the last update so I only get the new rows returned and not the whole database. The point is to have one main database on a remote server and multiple devices to be synchronized to it.

So next I need `Activities` to be able to query information from the local database using a loader which uses the `ContentProvider`.

Now I wonder whether there could be a problem with updating the database and querying it at the same time. Will the `ContentProvider` take care of that?
Also I need to synchronize a folder of pictures as well, how should I go about doing that?
Are there any synchronization issues I should be aware of?
And is there some better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: This sounds like a lot of questions at once, please try to narrow your questions down or ask multiple questions.

Comment: Well it may sound like a lot of questions, but the main aspect is that of Synchronization. How do I go about synchronizing a local SQLiteDatabase with a remote MySQL one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you that the endless loop inside the `Service` is a very bad idea. Especially with `Sleep(60000)`. Why don't you use an `IntentService` and the `AlarmManager`? An `IntentService` handles all `Intents` automatically in a background worker thread so you don't have to take care of that and the `AlarmManager` is basically just a timer with which you can invoke the Service every 60 seconds. That would be a much better solution for performing your updates.

As per your other questions: The `ContentProvider` already takes care of a lot of things for you. You don't have to worry abut concurrent requests or anything like that. And I can't really tell you much about the folder synchronisation, please try to be more specific. What specific problems worry you and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I look through your previous questions and you never actually accepted any answer, accepting an answer is a vital part of Stack Overflow. You can find more information [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: I've looked through them as well just now. Truth be told, only two of them were answered so I gave them credit(I guess I've forgotten to do so earlier), the rest had answers or comments made by me after some time has passed and I have solved the issue myself. And as for this question - I approve your answer, but I have asked more things, is my practice of doing things like this good? Should I synchronize like this or perhaps there is a more intelligent/out of the box way of doing so? Also about the pictures?

Comment: To clarify, I am not asking for you to accept my answer. It was just an observation that you never accepted any, not even your own one. As I said, asking multiple questions at once is not a good fit on Stack Overflow. The problem with asking multiple questions at once is that it is difficult to answer all of them at once. There might be one answer that has a correct answer to the first half of questions and another that answers the second half, so which answer do you accept than? For that and other reasons it is considered inappropriate to ask such questions.

Comment: I guess I understand where you come from. Indeed my question is a bit big, but still I am not asking for a very detailed answer, just a general direction - if my idea is okay or I should do something else.

Comment: Well it depends. If your app needs those frequent updates this might be the best strategy, but you need to consider that this might increase battery drain. The best option if you just want to send data to the devices would be using GCM. That way you can send data only if necessary for example if there are changes in the data and the devices can sleep for longer periods of time conserving battery and network traffic. And regarding your question about the pictures, you have to give me more information to help you out on that.

Comment: GCM looks interesting. About the images - I want the device to store a local copy of a folder with images. Example on my webserver I have: http://web.com/images - 10 images, I want the device to have a local folder images as well with them. And when some of the images change on the server, I want the device to get the new ones.